# Merge/synonym for [ai-openscale] with [watson-openscale]

Tags: support, status-completed, suggested-edits, synonym-request

**IBM AI OpenScale** was recently rebranded as the **IBM Watson OpenScale** in this [recent official announcement](https://newsroom.ibm.com/2019-02-12-IBM-Watson-Now-Available-Anywhere). We currently have the [ai-openscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ai-openscale) tag that is used on most of the questions for the service. As with any rebranding, it takes a while for everyone to get accustomed to it. We would like [watson-openscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watson-openscale) to be the master tag and [ai-openscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ai-openscale) to be a synonym tag. As I understand it, if someone added the [ai-openscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ai-openscale) tag to a question, it would then be automatically published as [watson-openscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watson-openscale).

Comment: Note: There are (currently) four [tag:watson-openscale] questions, all asked recently, all with the [tag:ai-openscale] tag.  There are two other older questions also branded [tag:ai-openscale] (for a total of six).

Comment: A moderator can merge these tags easily. Can you quickly confirm that all questions tagged [[tag:watson-openscale]] and [[tag:ai-openscale]] are about this same technology and are correctly tagged?

Comment: @ 1201ProgramAlarm @Cody Gray♦  Yes there are only a small set of current articles (issues) in SO since the service originally came out in 12/2018 and then was renamed last month.  I was able to tag all of them with both tags. However,I don't have the reputation points to implement the alteration to make 'ai-openscale' the synonym of 'watson-openscale' and was hoping an SO Admin could assist.

Comment: Sure, no worries. Just wanted to get double confirmation, since this type of merge is a destructive operation that doesn't leave any history. The shiniest buttons are also the most dangerous ones. :-) Done now; should be live immediately, minus caching effects.